# Sharing data between two table views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two table views that contain a mutable array of objects that can be instantiated by the user with various properties. The class and its properties are within separate `.h` and `.m` files that the table views access.

I would like the two table views to look identical so that when a user adds, deletes, or moves an object in one table view, the second table view is immediately updated. I understand that they will be sharing a mutable array, but I'm not sure where to put it so that changes in one table view occurs in the other table view.

Additionally, is this a situation in which I would make one of the table views a subclass of the other?

Comment: No, subclassing won't help here.  You simply need to write some code so that when a change is made to the data source that you reflect that change in the other tableview.  You could use a delegation pattern or an observer pattern using `Notification` for your data model.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First you should make a singleton class that contains that mutable array so you can edit/access it anywhere , whenever you update that array reload the visible tableView , if the other tableView is also visible reload it(either with delegate , observer , notificationCenter), otherwise it will be updated with the last edit when you open the VC that contains it , also you can make a use of `viewDidAppear` to reload the table inside it as another choice instead of delegates if it's the logic of your app

**// .h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalData : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray*masterArray;

+(GlobalData*)shared;

@end
```

**// .m**

```
#import "GlobalData.h"

@implementation GlobalData 

static GlobalData *instance = nil;

+(GlobalData *)shared
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if(instance==nil)
        {
            instance = [GlobalData new];

            instance.masterArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        }
    }
    return instance;
}


@end
```

**Usage**

```
  [GlobalData.shared.masterArray addObject:"strData"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I understand. I've tried to implement this in my project by creating a singleton class I'll call `Singleton`. In `Singleton.h` I have an `@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *masterArray;`. I know to `#import` the class in the table view file, but now I'm not exactly sure how to implement. I think I need to instantiate an object from the class: `Singleton *object  = [[Singleton alloc] init];` then access the `masterArray` property that way? Like `object.masterArray`. But how would I keep that object updated and in sync between both table views?

Comment: The example code was helpful. Singletons are done a little differently than I thought, thank you!

Comment: Downvote this cause the singleton won't focus the key of *identical*.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there is a controller owns the `NSMutableArray` object and the two table views.

- Use the `KVO` feature, let the two table view retain (use `strong` as property) the `NSMutableArray` object.
- Create a new delegates array property like `NSArray< id<MyArrayNotifier> > *delegates` for the `NSMutableArray` object's owner, implement the `MyArrayNotifier` protocol in two table view classes, add the table objects to `delegates` array. Now you could get notified when your focused message arrived.